# i want to save my xcode project as a base template to build others from how can i do this?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have added some base functionality to my xcode project but have more functionality to add, and in the sense of functionality 1, 2, 3 and 4. So I would like to take make four copies of my project to work on each piece of functionality rather than work on all functionality in the one project serially. Can anyone tell me the best thing to do?

Comment: Why can't you simply tar it up or use git to store it and then just unpack it and change when you want?  If you want to create a proper Xcode Template, then that's a different matter.

Comment: Thx trojanfoe, I am all "gitted" up now, much happier. BTW, what would tar do for me?

Comment: It's just a way of archiving files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Git repo and fork your project in 4 branches.

Comment: thats what I'm doing now, much apprceiated

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a version control system which will give you the benefits of working on individual parts of your program along with a simple way to bring them all together.

The idea of working on 4 individual copies is ill-conceived IMHO.

Comment: can you give an example of how VC would work in my case? I can't see it.